# jQuery Ajax POST to send multiple checkbox status to MVC4 controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have 20 check boxes and a submit button on my MVC4 razor page. User can select multiple check boxes(or can leave all of them unchecked) and click on the submit button. How can I get the selected check box values (yes/no) to my controller using a jQuery ajax POST .

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include "no" values as well for checkboxes, you might have to do something a little more hand-rolled; by default, serialize will not include checkbox values for ones that aren't checked, which can be seen in the jQuery documentation.

You could always iterate over the checkboxes with something like

`$("input[type='checkbox']")`

and use a for loop going over each one, including it in your JSON data to post to your server.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, serialize() on a form will give you all the values.  Then you just set this as the data in your post request.

```
 var attachment = $('form#yourFormId').serialize();
```